# ansible only run one of a with_item list limited by tags

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Im importing a usercreate role into an application role for the purpose of installing the application user only from the usercreate role. 
I'm having problems limiting the usercreate role to only create the application user. when imported it runs all of common/vars/users.yml defined users.

the tree:

```
└── roles
    ├── application-role
    |   └── tasks
    |       ├── main.yml
    |       └── application.yml
    └── common
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── tasks
        │   ├── main.yml
        │   └── usercreation.yml
        └── vars
            ├── main.yml
            └── users.yml
```

the application task:

```
- name: create applicationuser from commonrole
  become: yes
  include_role:
    name: common
    tasks_from: usercreation.yml
    vars_from: users.yml
    public: yes
    apply:
      tags: present-test
  vars:
    username: applicationuser
  tags: usertest1
```

and the common usercreate task:

```
 - include_vars: users.yml
   tags: present-test

 - name: Create users
   become: yes
   user:
     name: "{{ item.username }}"
     shell: "{{ item.shell }}"
     groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
     createhome: yes
     comment: "{{ item.comment }}"
     password: "{{ item.OSpass }}"
     uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
     state: "{{ item.status }}"
   with_items:
     "{{ users }}"
   tags: present-test
```

and lastly the users.yml

```
users:
  - username: applicationuser
    comment: "ansible test user 2 "
    shell: "/bin/bash"
    profile: prod
    uid: "599"
    dev: no
    key: "ssh-rsa AAAAAxxXXxxXX666666666XX66X"
    groups: "wheel"
    OSpass: "$6$9rywWxjz4XFDxQ2H$mb1qvD1dGe.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxHSrcwfCmqa438WqEqg/eV/IY3KjRjBty56spCOUsxfNH/"
    status: present

  - username: otheruser
...
```

when running this it creates all users in the vars/users.yml, totally ignoring my vars: limitation

I would like to only create the applicationuser.

Is it doable  ?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your 'username', but you aren't actually doing anything with that variable.

Perhaps you intended to add a 'when' or something?  Something like this perhaps?

```
 - name: Create users
   become: yes
   user:
     name: "{{ item.username }}"
     shell: "{{ item.shell }}"
     groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
     createhome: yes
     comment: "{{ item.comment }}"
     password: "{{ item.OSpass }}"
     uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
     state: "{{ item.status }}"
   with_items:
     "{{ users }}"
   tags: present-test
   when: username == item.username
```

Comment: Hi. sorry forgot that sniplet,
username is a reference to users.yml, that I included in the usercreate task
( - include_vars: users.yml )

Comment: but yes; a when would be great.
like in:
when: [ tag present-test, then only create user applicationuser; else create adminusers only ]
or something like that